# TextWatcher для нескольких editText'ов + изменение положения View элемента относительно View элемента из дочернего Layout'а

Tags: java, android

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ФИНАЛ**

В общем, плохая идея пользовать EditText'ы для таких целей. Правильных решений много, но изящное только одно. И начинается оно с выбора наиболее подходящего View элемента.

**НАЧАЛО**

У меня есть TableLayout, в нём по весу распределены аж целых 30 editText'ов. В родительском RelativeLayout лежит ListView:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/scroll"
android:id="@+id/tablo">
<TableRow
   android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text3"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/text"
   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text">
<EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:ems="3"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text"/>
<EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:ems="3"
       android:inputType="text"/>
...
</TableRow>
...
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/text"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text">
...
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText30"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="3"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lvFirst"
        android:visibility="invisible"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на любой из этих editText'ов, происходило следующее:

```
{ TextWatcher определяет, по какому тексту я тапаю;
  этому тексту присваивается id "используемый";
  устанавливаются параметры для ListView:
  (видимость и положение под id "используемый"); 
  также к ListView применяется фильтр; }
```

Фильтр для одного editText'а я реализовал с помощью textChangedListener:

```
EditText editText1;
String[] data = {"item1","item2","item3","item4"};
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    lvFirst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvFirst);
    lvFirst.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lvFirst.setAdapter(adapter1);

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           MainActivity.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(arg0);

       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                     int arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });
}
```

**Обновление**

Эти editText'ы - своего рода поисковые поля, через которые я ищу одно и то же: содержимое ListView. Я бы описал задачу так: просто присвоить textChangedListener из последнего кода для всех editText'ов. Но проблема в том, что ListView должен менять своё местоположение в зависимости от используемого editText'а. Для этого нужно определить, какой текст используется, присвоить ему специальный id и от него уже плясать.

Comment: Эти 30 `EditText` какие то поля, по которым нужно фильтровать содержимое `ListView` чтоли? Опишите алгоритм самой решаемой задачи подробнее

Comment: Конкретнее, в чем вопрос?